# Java no token in next line but there should be?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner, token

```
public static void flipLines(Scanner input) {
    int i = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String ignore = input.nextLine();
        if (i >= 0) {
            System.out.println(input.nextLine());
            System.out.println(ignore);
        } i++;
    }
}
```

I have this and I'm trying to flip lines from an input from scanner. I get a token error that says there is no line there when reading this text only on the very last line. Below is what it's supposed to look like when completely flipped but you can see in my version I lack the last line due to an error.

```
did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
Twas brillig and the slithy toves
and the mome raths outgrabe.
All mimsey were the borogroves,
"Beware the Jabberwock, my son,

Beware the JubJub bird and shun
the jaws that bite, the claws that catch,
the frumious bandersnatch."
```

Here is the error and the output with flipped lines program. I have no idea why it would be out of token index when it should be printing the last line instead.

```
did gyre and gimble in the wabe.
Twas brillig and the slithy toves
and the mome raths outgrabe.
All mimsey were the borogroves,
"Beware the Jabberwock, my son,

Beware the JubJub bird and shun
the jaws that bite, the claws that catch,
NoSuchElementException on line 9:
No tokens remain in input.  Near input line 9

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No tokens remain in input.  Near input line 9
    at Scanner._getNoSuchElementException(Scanner.java:1549)
    at Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1254)
    at flipLines (Line 9)
```

Comment: Walk through your code as it's running using a debugger.

Comment: You're double calling `input.NextLine()` within the while loop.  That's causing the exception (since it get to the final line and tries to read the next 2 lines).  Keep in mind that `NextLine()` advances the scanner.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Best way is probably to [explain it to a rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 3):

If the number of lines is odd, you cannot safely assume that you can call nextLine twice after checking that it exists only once. You need an additional check inside the while loop body.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to solve it thanks to you guys for making me read my code more carefully. I added an extra condition in the if statement and it works good now!

```
public static void flipLines(Scanner input) {
    int i = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String ignore = input.nextLine();
        if (i >= 0 && input.hasNextLine()) {
            String keep = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(keep);
        } i++;
          System.out.println(ignore);
    }
}
```